# Tmux: keep accidentally resizing pane instead of switching to the next one

Tags: tmux

Tmux is excellent, but there is one quirk that is proving to be a pane. If I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> then go too fast to the arrow key in order to switch panes I end up just resizing the current pane. It would be very nice to get rid of that behaviour. Is this a problem solvable in tmux or is in some kind of lag in my OS?

Answer (score 1):

`tmux` is fully configurable so, yes, it's possible to solve this issue.

I suggest that you take a look at the [`tmux` man pages](https://man.cx/tmux(1)) or at other  resources like [Pragmatic Bookshelf's "tmux 2" book](https://pragprog.com/book/bhtmux2/tmux-2).

As an example, you can fully remap the keys to use to split, move around and resize windows adding something like this to your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
# Splitting panes
bind | split-window -h                  # Uses "|" to split pane horizontally
bind - split-window -v                  # Uses "-" to split pane vertically

# Remapping movement keys
bind h select-pane -L                   # Move focus to pane on the left
bind j select-pane -D                   # Move focus to pane above the current one
bind k select-pane -U                   # Move focus to pane below the current one
bind l select-pane -R                   # Move focus to pane on the right
bind -r C-h select-window -t :-         # Move to previous window
bind -r C-l select-window -t :+         # Move to next window

# Resizing panes (notes that is using the uppercase here and resize by 5 chars)
bind -r H resize-pane -L 5
bind -r J resize-pane -D 5
bind -r K resize-pane -U 5
bind -r L resize-pane -R 5
```